# Shopify python API command working in html view but not in views.py file

Tags: django, python-2.7, shopify

Provided this python code for a Shopify app:

```
with request.user.session:
    products = shopify.Product.find()    
for product in products:
    if product.variants.0.inventory_management:
        make_call()
```

So, when I use product.variants.0.inventory_management in my view file called "home.html", it displays the value "shopify" which makes sense. But when I use the exact same thing in the code example above I get a syntax error and my django app shows the error log. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`variants` is presumably a list. In python you use square brackets to index a list:

```
if product.variants[0].inventory_management:
```